# Error while using $url ,from response headers of 1st Curl, in 2nd Curl , but writing url manually works

Tags: php, curl

i get next url from 1st curl's response and in echo its showing the url but when 1 put $url in 2nd curl it does not work until i write the url manually in $ch = curl_init('www.example1.com'); like this
my php script is;

```
1st Curl


$ch = curl_init('www.example.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_GET, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$headers = [];
$output = rtrim($output);
$data = explode("\n",$output);
$headers = $data[8];
$url = substr($headers, 10);

echo $url;
```

/////   echo is working and showing url but in below curl it does not work when i put $url or '.$url.'
but when i put it manually it works ..... can you give any suggestions?
I also tried to save url in a text file and get it from there for 2nd Curl but no use

```
2nd Curl


$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: What is this line `$url = json_decode(json_encode($url));` supposed to achieve?

Comment: @El_Vanja i don't know if that's what OP is going for, but i can tell you what it does: it removes formatting from a json, eg if the json is pretty-printed and you want to remove the pretty from it, that's the way to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

most likely invisible/unprintable characters.

my best guess: there's an invisible carriage-return byte at the end of $url which invalidates your url, because your header extraction code is buggy. try running the url through this function to verify:

```
function f(string $url){
    $needles = array(
        "carriage-return"=>"\r",
        "newline"=>"\n",
        "null"=>"\x00"
    );
    for($i=0;$i<strlen($url);++$i){
        $found = array_search($url[$i],$needles,true);
        if($found!==false){
            echo "byte #{$i} contains: {$found} byte.\n";
        }
    }
    
}
```

if i'm right, it should print something like: `byte #19 contains: carriage-return byte.`

another thing you can do is to run it through `echo bin2hex($url);` and cross-reference every byte with https://asciitable.com to look for non-printable characters.

Comment: THANKS, ITS SOLVED NOW

Comment: @SoulfulRecites btw the fix for your header parser would be to replace `$data = explode("\n",$output);` with `$data = explode("\r\n",$output);` - for http headers, the carriage-return byte is part of the header-separator ^^